# Generating Link from .Net Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have this class:

```
public class Link {
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Url { get; set:}
     public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to pass this to the view (A page of links), such that each Link.Title will appear as the clickable link text with Link.Url as the URL.

How exactly do I pass the model properties into a clickable link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a collection of Link object to your view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var links = new List<Link>{
    new Link { Title="StackOverFlow", Url="http://www.stackoverflow.com", 
                                                                      Description="SO"},
    new Link { Title="SuperUser", Url="http://www.superuser.com",
                                                                      Description="SU"}
  };
  return View(links);
}
```

and your view, which is strongly typed to a collection of Link objects, simply loop through them and build the markup you want.

```
@IEnumerable<Link>
@foreach(var link in Model)
{
   <a href="@link.Url" title="@link.Description">@link.Title</a>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but why the "title = "@link.Description""?  why not <a href="@link.Url">@link.Title</a>?

Comment: I thought you use the Description property for your title attribute(the small tool tip when you hover over). If you do not want it, just remove it.